# Function that validates the environment dev or prod serverless framework

Tags: node.js, odoo, serverless-framework

I am getting a price list from an odoo database
I have two environments dev and prod.

In dev I want to run it like this

```
async function getPrice() {
try {
    const server = await odoo.getConnection();

    const domain = FILTER_ODOO;

    const params = [];
    params.push([domain]);
    params.push({
        fields: ['id', 'price_list_odoo', 'price_whith_iva']
    });

    const prices = await Odooserver.execute_kw('product.template', 'search_read', params);
    info('get_prices_complete', {prices});
    return prices;
} catch (error) {
    fail('error_get_prices_complete', error);
}
return [];
}
```

and in prod I want to execute it in this other way
What changes is to use the **price_list_odoo** field
by
**price_lst_odoo**

```
async function getPrice() {
try {
    const server = await odoo.getConnection();
    const domain = FILTER_ODOO;
    const params = [];
    params.push([domain]);
    params.push({
        fields: ['id', '**price_lst_odoo**', 'price_whith_iva']
    });

    const prices = await Odooserver.execute_kw('product.template', 'search_read', params);
    info('get_prices_complete', {prices});
    return prices;
} catch (error) {
    fail('error_get_prices_complete', error);
}
return [];
}
```

How can I make a function that validates when I'm in prod and dev
I am using aws and serverless framework.

[image: I already have a stage dev for both environments]